# Java Selenium with Angular 5

Tags: java, angular, selenium

I am trying to work with Selenium in Java with Angular 5 based website.
Selenium does not support it directly, but `JavascriptExecutor` can help validating the page components finished loading.

The problem is, I do not know how to implement the JavaScript to validate this.

I am using:

`return window.getAngularTestability === undefined`

to validate Angular 5 exists in the current page, but the next part of the implementation is a mystery to me.

I know I have to use `return window.getAngularTestability` somehow.

Comment: Can you update the question with _how_  you are using `return window.getAngularTestability === undefined` currently and how differently you want it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use JavaScript with Selenium WebDriver Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430773/how-to-use-javascript-with-selenium-webdriver-java)

Comment: @JeffC this is not relevant for my question, not duplicate of the issue you linked. thank you for your input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer after a lot of research and searching the web.

The solution is not mine, so i do not deserve the credit.

```
ExpectedCondition<Boolean> expectation = driver -> ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeAsyncScript(
            "var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];" +
                    "if (document.readyState !== 'complete') {" +
                    "  callback('document not ready');" +
                    "} else {" +
                    "  try {" +
                    "    var testabilities = window.getAllAngularTestabilities();" +
                    "    var count = testabilities.length;" +
                    "    var decrement = function() {" +
                    "      count--;" +
                    "      if (count === 0) {" +
                    "        callback('complete');" +
                    "      }" +
                    "    };" +
                    "    testabilities.forEach(function(testability) {" +
                    "      testability.whenStable(decrement);" +
                    "    });" +
                    "  } catch (err) {" +
                    "    callback(err.message);" +
                    "  }" +
                    "}"
    ).toString().equals("complete");
    try {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver(), 15);
        wait.until(expectation);
    } catch (Throwable error) {
        new Exception("Timeout waiting for Page Load Request to complete.");
    }
```

Comment: If the solution isn't yours, you should at least link to where you got it to give them credit.

Comment: unfortunately, it was a late night and a long research so i can't find it now.

Comment: Most likely this is the source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49410819

Answer (score 0):

You can create a generic java method for running any javascript within your Java code. Refer below block of code:-

```
 public void executeJavascript(String script) {
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(script);
    }
```

You can pass your `return` javascript statements as *parameters* to this method.