# Testing AngularJS with Selenium using PHP

Tags: php, angular, selenium

"wait for page loads / jquery.ajax (if present) and $http calls, and any accompanying digest/render cycle, throw it in a utility function and wait away"

Does anyone have a PHP + Selenium utility function for following solution provided by
npjohns in

[Testing AngularJS with Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25062969/testing-angularjs-with-selenium) ?