# Selenium c# code required to wait till full page is loaded

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Below are the steps for which code is required:

**1) Open 1 page**

**2) Page loading**

(i)First showing loading symbol into tab, ["All elements inside the page is clickable and visible, so I assume explicit wait will not work"]

[image: Tab Loader Symbol]

(ii)After few seconds showing javascript loader and then page is loading fully.

[image: Javascript Loader]

In a conclusion, I need solution for Step 2.

Comment: This is the complete solution, and you can use same : https://stackoverflow.com/a/41617476/9405154

Comment: I really appreciate Ishita for your prompt reply! Let me try and get back to you soon. Again thanks :)